# arrow_binary data type in R df

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I'm trying to create an R dataframe by using arrow's read_parquet function. The parquet file is stored in S3. When I read in the file, many of the columns are of type arrow_binary. How can I read in these columns as strings?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways you could do this; either via `read_parquet()` and then cast the column type, or via `open_dataset()` and supplying a schema.

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
tbl <- arrow_table(iris)

# change Species to binary
tbl <- tbl %>%
  mutate(Species = cast(Species, binary())) %>%
  collect()

# create a temporary directory
tf <- tempfile()
dir.create(tf)

# save the file with a binary column
write_parquet(tbl, file.path(tf, "iris.parquet"))

# if we read it in as-is the last column is binary
file_in <- read_parquet(file.path(tf, "iris.parquet"), as_data_frame = FALSE)
file_in
#> Table
#> 150 rows x 5 columns
#> $Sepal.Length <double>
#> $Sepal.Width <double>
#> $Petal.Length <double>
#> $Petal.Width <double>
#> $Species <binary>
#> 
#> See $metadata for additional Schema metadata

# we can cast to a string via mutate()
file_in %>% mutate(Species = cast(Species, string())) 
#> Table (query)
#> Sepal.Length: double
#> Sepal.Width: double
#> Petal.Length: double
#> Petal.Width: double
#> Species: string (cast(Species, {to_type=string, allow_int_overflow=false, allow_time_truncate=false, allow_time_overflow=false, allow_decimal_truncate=false, allow_float_truncate=false, allow_invalid_utf8=false}))
#> 
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object

# alternatively, we can specify a schema to the dataset
open_dataset(
  tf,
  schema = schema(
    Sepal.Length = float64(), Sepal.Width = float64(), Petal.Length = float64(), 
    Petal.Width = float64(), Species = string()
  )
)
#> FileSystemDataset with 1 Parquet file
#> Sepal.Length: double
#> Sepal.Width: double
#> Petal.Length: double
#> Petal.Width: double
#> Species: string
```

Comment: why doesn't `Species = as.character(Species)` work here?

Comment: `cast` isn't working for me, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76182450/read-csv-arrow-unable-to-deal-with-extended-latin-character-set