# read_csv_arrow unable to deal with extended latin character set in Windows

Tags: r, csv, apache-arrow

I have a csv, on windows:

```
name, age
Siân, 34
Brónagh, 45
François, 87
Alan, 23
,
```

I try to read this into R using:

```
library(arrow)
df <- read_csv_arrow("people.csv")
```

It loads the table but converts the `name` column to `arrow_binary`

dput output:

```
structure(list(name = structure(list(as.raw(c(0x53, 0x69, 0xe2, 0x6e)), 
                                            as.raw(c(0x42, 0x72, 0xf3, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x67,0x68)), 
                                            as.raw(c(0x46, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6e, 0xe7, 0x6f, 0x69, 0x73)), 
                                            as.raw(c(0x41, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x6e)), NULL), 
                                       class = c("arrow_binary", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried to do an explicity conversion of this column:

```
as.character(df$name)
> Can't convert `x` <arrow_binary> to <character>.
```

I've also tried to use `arrows` `cast` command following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766202/arrow-binary-data-type-in-r-df/73976290)

```
df %>% mutate(name = arrow::cast(name, string()))
```

But it can't find `cast`

```
> ! 'cast' is not an exported object from 'namespace:arrow'
```

Additionally, I've tried defining the datatype in the `read_csv_arrow`

```
read_csv_arrow("people.csv",
               col_types = schema(name = arrow::string()))
```

but this gives:

```
> ! Invalid: In CSV column #1: Row #1: CSV conversion error to string: invalid UTF8 data
```

I would like to use uft16, but it doesn't appear to be a datatype that [arrow accepts](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/data-type.html)

Comment: I've added the dput, I can't get your purrr code to work on it: `! argument 'x' must be a raw vector`. Is your's working?

Comment: I suppose that's my issue, how do I read in with correct encoding. The actual dataset is huge so I'm trying to provide a reproducible example.  How should null be stored with `as.raw`

Comment: You can set `encoding` in `CsvReadOptions`: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/CsvReadOptions.html

Comment: Try `read_csv_arrow("people.csv", read_options = list(encoding = "latin1"))`.  Thank you Alistaire.

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento that solves it, feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept